# How can we install libmemcached on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, php, nginx, memcached

I am trying to use php memcache extension on Ubuntu 18.04 (nginx + PHP 7.2). Memcached is installed and working but I could not get the `php-memcache` extension working.

I can install libmemcached11 without any problems:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmemcached11

libmemcached11 is already the newest version (1.0.18-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+2).
```

When I run:

```
$ sudo apt install libmemcached-dev

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmemcached-dev : Depends: libmemcached11 (= 1.0.18-4.2ubuntu0.18.04.1) but 1.0.18-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 is to be installed
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update`  first, to update the package repository (list over available and current packages).

Comment: You have a Xenial version of `libmemcached11` installed from a PPA. The PPA was probably disabled during an upgrade to Bionic, so you should re-enable it.

Comment: @fkraiem can you please elaborate a little more? I could not find any disabled ppa's..

Answer (score 10):

I have solved the problem by checking for any leftovers of xenial ppa's and removing them. Then I uninstalled **libmemcached11** by:

```
sudo apt-get remove libmemcached11
```

And than installing **libmemcached-dev** by:

```
sudo apt-get install libmemcached-dev
```

I hope this solution helps somebody..